# Having problems setting up directx12 (Cant include windows.h)

Tags: c++, directx

I'm following the Frank Luna directX12 book, I have installed the windows 10 SDK etc but now, when I compile any project from his demo they wont build. Error I am getting is Cannot open source file which I have never had a problem including before I installed windows 10 SDK, any suggestions? If any more info is needed let me know

Comment: Which source file in particular? Are you using VS 2015? Have you set the Target Platform Version to a 10.0 version number? See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/07/29/developing-for-windows-10-with-visual-c-2015/)

Comment: Wow this was a while ago, but it turns out it was the target platform version, as you mentioned @ChuckWalbourn Cheers